# RecyclerView doesn't get updated

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

The problem is that my RecyclerView doesn't get updated unless I set a new adapter.
Here's the code:

```
    TransferLab transferLab = TransferLab.get(getActivity());
    List<Transfer> transfers = transferLab.getTransfers();

    if (mAdapter == null) {
        mAdapter = new TransferAdapter(transfers);
        mTransferRecyclerView.setAdapter(new TransferAdapter(transfers));
    } else {
        mAdapter.setTransfers(transfers);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

As you see I get a new list and pass it into the adapter. But the RecyclerView doesn't change until I restart the app or replace the IF-section with the code below:

```
        mAdapter = new TransferAdapter(transfers);
        mTransferRecyclerView.setAdapter(new TransferAdapter(transfers));
```

Inside the adapter:

```
    private class TransferAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TransferViewHolder> {

    private List<Transfer> mTransfers;


    public TransferAdapter(List<Transfer> transfers) {
        mTransfers = transferList;
    }

    public void setTransfers(List<Transfer> transfers) {
        mTransfers = transfers;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public TransferViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
        return new TransferViewHolder(inflater, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TransferViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(mTransfers.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mTransfers.size();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the whole code of your `TransferAdapter` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting `mAdapter` to your `mTransferRecyclerView` but rather creating a new instance of `TransferAdapter` and setting that instead. As a result, `mAdapter` is not set to any RecyclerView and updating it does nothing.

Change this part of your code:

```
mTransferRecyclerView.setAdapter(new TransferAdapter(transfers));
```

to

```
mTransferRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

P.S. I would actually suggest you to remove `List<Transfer> transfers` from constructor of your TransferAdapter class and initialize your field `private List<Transfer> mTransfers;` to empty list. Then after inflating views create an instance of adapter and set it to RecyclerView immediately. When data is ready later you can call your `setTransfers` method and notify adapter.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Stupid mistake. Sorry to have bothered you.

Comment: @Alex No worries, stupid mistakes can happen. Please consider accepting and upvoting my answer

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be implemented this way

```
public void setTransfers(List<Transfer> transfers) {
            mTransfers.clear() //clear the old data
            Collections.copy(mTransfers, transfers) //copy the new data to old empty list
        }
```